# Problem with wifi adapter mercury mw300uh

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, adapter

I am after fresh installation of Kubuntu , and it doesnt recognize my usb wifi adapter
lsusb :

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0e8d:2005 MediaTek Inc. Redmi 6A
Bus 001 Device 009: ID ffff:5678 USB Disk 2.0
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2c4e:0104 Mercucys INC 802.11n NIC 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e8d:1887 MediaTek Inc. Slim Portable DVD Writer
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b05:19af ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:705f A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Device 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have gone though other people driver installation problem but even tho it doesnt work.
Does anyone have solution for this wifi adapter driver installation ?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add "solved", "answered", etc. Accepting an answer like you have already done is enough to mark a question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms bc
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I was trying to actually install it before from this git but as I see , I did it wrong . Now all is set up .